# Angular 2 routerLink optional route part

Tags: angular2-routing

I want to achieve something like this with a relative routerlink:

```
[routerLink]=[routePart, 'Create']
```

where routePart is a component property and can be empty, meaning it should be ignored, or have some value

So if current route is '/Products' then if

routePart = '' we want to get '/Products/Create'

routePart = 'xyz' we want to get '/Product/xyz/Create'

But what I find in the first case it becomes an absolute path and resolves to '/Create'

I can get it working using an expression in the binding but this seems kinda ugly

```
[routerLink]='routePart == '' ? 'Create' : 'xyz/Create''
```

Is there some clean way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<a *ngIf="routePart === '' " [routerLink]="Create" />

<a *ngIf="routePart === 'xyz' " [routerLink]="xyz/Create" />
```